# is there a default timeout value in rust/tonic crate?

Tags: rust, grpc

The default connection sets the timeout value to none and I think I might be missing something here. Any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In our experience, and from [here](https://grpc.io/blog/deadlines/), the default value for request (or response) timeout seems to be the same as the underlying GRPC deadline, which, according to the documentation, is **very high**.

In our case, we only needed `connect_timeout` and the [default value](https://gkkachi.github.io/firestore-grpc/tonic/transport/struct.Endpoint.html#method.connect_timeout) is **`no timeout`**.

If you need to use `keep_alive_timeout` (http2), the default value is `hyper`'s [default value](https://docs.rs/hyper/latest/hyper/server/struct.Builder.html#method.http2_keep_alive_timeout): **20 seconds**